# Using ArcGIS Javascript API and need help understanding asynchronous programming in accessing the fields property of a FeatureLayer Object

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm creating a new FeatureLayer, and I want to populate the popup with a list of all the fields. Here is part of my code:

```js
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(url, {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields:["*"],
    infoTemplate: popupTemplate
});
var fieldArray1 = featureLayer.fields;
console.log(fieldArray1); // output: undefined

// But, this gives me what I want:
setTimeout(function(){
    var fieldArray2 = featureLayer.fields;
    console.log(fieldArray2); //output: an array of Field Objects
},5000);
```

I believe one of my problems is that I don't fully how to handle the fact that javascript is asynchronous. I realize that `var fieldArray1 = featureLayer.fields;` is executing before the FeatureLayer Object finished being created.

What is the correct and best way to code what I want to do, which is - "after the new FeatureLayer Object is created, set fieldArray1 = featureLayer.fields?"

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer.html#event-load

In JavaScript if code is asynchronous, should be provided an event / callback function that fires once the code is done. It seems there's a `load` event. So, try something like this :

```
featureLayer.on('load', function(response){
  console.log(response.layer.fields);
});
```

Comment: The response Object looks like this: {layer: Object, target: Object}. So, this works: `...function(response){console.log(response.layer.fields);});`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Uuups! Just a mistake, I have never used ArcGIS JavaScript API. I'll update my anwser. ;P